# ¿Cómo calcular la moda de un valor en DataFrame en función de otra columna?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame:

```
Combustible Comunidad_autonoma         Año_de_venta  \
```

0          Diésel            Navarra  2020-12-18 10:47:13
1        Gasolina     Islas Canarias  2021-01-02 11:25:40
5        Gasolina             Madrid  2021-01-08 17:03:33
6          Diésel     Islas Baleares  2021-01-12 11:26:18
7          Diésel           Cataluña  2020-12-03 15:35:56
...           ...                ...                  ...
49995    Gasolina          Andalucia  2020-11-24 19:59:52
49996      Diésel          Andalucia  2021-01-13 17:02:41
49997    Gasolina          Andalucia  2021-01-08 16:47:24
49998    Gasolina            Galicia  2021-01-13 16:22:53
49999      Diésel           Cataluña  2021-01-10 16:32:41

```
               Marca_y_Modelo
```

0                     SEAT Toledo
1                      CITROEN C1
5                    PEUGEOT 3008
6      LAND-ROVER Discovery Sport
7                     HONDA Civic
...                           ...
49995                 HYUNDAI i30
49996              RENAULT Laguna
49997                 PEUGEOT 108
49998                    AUDI RS4
49999                  CITROEN C2

[47294 rows x 4 columns]

Necesito saber que Combustible es la moda en función de la Marca_y_Modelo, para después rellenar los NaN de combustible en función de esa moda por Marca_y_Modelo.

he intentado lo siguiente:

```
esto=cochesusados.groupby([ 'Marca_y_Modelo','Combustible']).agg(lambda x:x.mode().index[0])

for i in cochesusados['Marca_y_Modelo']:
    if i in listacoches:
        cochesusados['Combustible'][i].mode()

df = (cochesusados.groupby('Marca_y_Modelo')['Combustible']
               .apply(lambda x: x.mode().iat[0])
               .reset_index())
```

Comment: ya lo he hecho!

Comment: Buen día, que bueno que solucionaste tu problema. Te recomiendo crear una respuesta para que sea visible para la comunidad o cerrar la pregunta. Las preguntas que quedan abiertas por siempre no son de utilidad para la comunidad. Saludos!

Comment: no, no lo resolvi.....ya cambié la pregunta para dar más detalles que me pidieron, pero no lo he conseguido resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Una forma fácil de hacerlo es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y aplicar una función `lambda` utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). La función debe obtener la media, para eso podemos utilizar [`pandas.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) y rellenar los `NaN` con [`pandas.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` como ejemplo:

```
  Combustible Marca_y_Modelo
0      Diesel              A
1    Gasolina              B
2         NaN              B
3      Diesel              A
4    Gasolina              A
5      Diesel              A
6    Gasolina              B
7         NaN              A
8         NaN              B
9      Diesel              B
```

Código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Combustible': ['Diesel', 'Gasolina', np.nan, 'Diesel', 'Gasolina', 'Diesel', 'Gasolina', np.nan, np.nan, 'Diesel'],
                   'Marca_y_Modelo': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B']})

df = df.groupby(['Marca_y_Modelo'], group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().iloc[0]))
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
  Combustible Marca_y_Modelo
0      Diesel              A
1    Gasolina              B
2    Gasolina              B
3      Diesel              A
4    Gasolina              A
5      Diesel              A
6    Gasolina              B
7      Diesel              A
8    Gasolina              B
9      Diesel              B
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! Funciona a la perfección.

Comment: No hay de que. Te recomiendo visitar todas las referencias a la documentación para entender el funcionamiento completo de cada una de esas funciones. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! la verdad que a la hora de comprobarlo no da del todo bien.. como lo podría comprobar?

Comment: @Anitta ¿En qué casos no funciona bien? Tal vez sea conveniente crear una nueva pregunta para que puedas mostrar los datos que utilizas (Podrías agregar algunas filas del `dataframe` que hagan que no funcione correctamente) y el código completo